# Cannot read property 'split' of undefined in ionic image upload

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I tried testing my ionic image upload app in browser but since I can not upload image due to cordova_not_available been displayed on the screen, every time I click ed on the upload button this error pop up **Cannot read property 'split' of undefined**

in my upload.ts i have this

```
let filename = this.imagePath.split('/').pop();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because your variable `this.imagePath` is null or empty... how are you getting the value?